# Incorrect Data Order Returned

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have an MySQL data:

[image: MySql Data]

I try to get fetch them using jquery:

```
         $.post(
            '../php/teacheradminfunction.php',
            {'functions':'getBadgeImg','topicSkill':$('#selTeachAdminBadgeDeleteSkill').val()},
            function(data) {
                $.each(data, function( key, value ) {
                    alert( key + ": " + value.badge_path );
                });
            },'JSON'
        );
```

My PHP script:

```
$queryStmt = 'SELECT badge_path FROM badges WHERE badge_skill=:sqlSkill ORDER BY `index` ASC';
        $queryPrepare = $dba_connect->prepare($queryStmt);
        $queryPrepare->execute(array(':sqlSkill'=>$_POST['topicSkill']));
        $queryResult = $queryPrepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $queryPrepare->closeCursor();

        echo json_encode($queryResult);
```

My problem is that I needed to have the correct order, what I get is:

```
[{"badge_path":"..\\image\\badges\\Counting10_g.png"},{"badge_path":"..\\image\\badges\\Counting10_b.png"},{"badge_path":"..\\image\\badges\\Counting10_s.png"}]
```

Expected result :

```
[{"badge_path":"..\\image\\badges\\Counting10_g.png"},{"badge_path":"..\\image\\badges\\Counting10_s.png"},{"badge_path":"..\\image\\badges\\Counting10_b.png"}]
```

Comment: By `order` it is returning correct data.

Comment: you have to edit in your record because the result of your query is right..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Give proper index  in your database. According to your query it's return correct records.

```
index    badge_rank
  1       GOLD
  2       SILVER
  3       BRONZE
```

Comment: What makes it incorrect was the "HOW" did I inserted my data, I kinda switch the Silver and Bronze data. With your answer, I have realize this and made corrections.

Answer (score -1):

You could also select the Index or "badge_rank" and use this as key:value as JSON instead of an array of objects.

Your easiest way is to change the Index of your badge_path to the correct order.

1. Gold,
2. Silver,
3. Bronce

Answer (score -1):

change the index value in database
modify the index value for Counting10_s.png and make it 2
and likewise change the index value for Counting10_b.png and make it 3

Since you are using order by index hence the rows are sorted based on the index value. Modifying the index value will give you the desired output